# PHP: remove last comma of a multipolygon

Tags: php, regex, polygons, wkt

I have following issue:
I import WKT dynamicaly from DB into WKT Wicket Javascript library. I must do some substitutions to fit the WKT correctly. Since mysql fetches WKT AsText(SHAPE) i recive several arrays e.g. POLYGON((xxxx)),POLYGON((yyyy)) and so on. 
First, I had to remove all "POLYGON" doing

```
$str = preg_replace('/^POLYGON/', '', $WKT[1]);
```

and add MULTIPOLYGON before `<?php`

tag in the wicket. It works.
Second, I must add comma between polygons, preicisely between "))((" brackets:

```
$str2 = str_replace(array('((', '))'), array('((', ')),'), $str);
```

It works but last comma remains what "slightly" deforms my multipolygon:
MULTIPOLYGON((xxx)),((yyy)),((zzz)),

How can I remove last comma?

I would be thankful for every regex or some other solution which can solve my problem.

Comment: `str_replace()`. use that

Comment: Use `$str2 = rtrim($str2, ",")` after you did `str_replace`, Look [here](http://php.net/rtrim).

Comment: I tried preg_replace, rtrim, various regexes but. it always removes all commas.

Comment: Look [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f324c4498a09aabf0ffd5c9143188b63f50c5a6) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any string, you can remove the last X if you are sure that no X follows. So, you can use a negative lookahead: `(,)(?!.*,)`, as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/nG6lS0/3) and replace it with empty string.

`$result = preg_replace('/(,)(?!.*,)/', '', $str)`

This doesn't look at the context though, it will just remove the last comma of any string, no matter where it is.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you both - your answers were right and very helpful.

The problem was not string replacement. It was more the data fetching from DB.
Mysqli_fetch_array and mysqli_fetch_assoc return stringstringsring or arrayarrayarray for 3 rows fetched. That is why all commas were replaced.

I changed to `mysqli_fetch_all` ,then did minor replacements for each row (as array) and  implode each one as variable. After i merged  them into single variable, then I could apply your solutions. It is not sofisticated solution, but if it is packed into function it'll be fine.

```
($WKT = mysqli_fetch_all($result)) {
$str = preg_replace('/POLYGON/', '', $WKT[0]);
$str1 = preg_replace('/POLYGON/', '', $WKT[1]);
$str2 = preg_replace('/POLYGON/', '', $WKT[2]);
$str3 = implode($str);
$str4 = implode($str1);
$str5 = implode($str2);
$str6 = $str3 . $str4 . $str5;
$str7 = preg_replace('/\)\)/', ')),', $str6);
$str8 = rtrim($str7, ",");
echo $str8;
}
```